# Why regression is considered as part of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

If by Machine Learning (ML) we mean **any program that learns from data**, then, yes, regression can be said to be part of ML. But there are several other aspects to Machine Learning such as : **solution is improved iteratively based on some performance measure**. Whereas for linear regression there is a closed form solution in the form of a direct formula using which all the parameters can be determined and it does not involve iterations. But there is other version of parameter estimation for regression that makes use of gradient descent and it involves several iterations. Does it mean that this iterative version of parameter estimation for regression is done forcefully to bring regression under machine learning umbrella? Or the iterative version has some advantages that the direct formula does not offer?

Comment: Where have you found this definition of ML? On Wikipedia it says nothing about the requirement of an iterative approach.

Comment: Today, the term of *Machine Learning* is overly used, and lots of algorithms, terms and definitions that fit in the description of ML are just concepts of *statistics*, so ML is just a big marketing term for "statistical methods"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't comment on whether regression is part of ML or not (I don't really see where your definitions came from). But regarding the advantage of an iterative approach, please note that the closed-form solution for linear regression is as follows:

[image: Linear Regression Analytical Solution]

Where X is your design matrix.
Please note that inverting a matrix is an O(n^3) operation, which is infeasible for large n. This is the obvious advantage of the iterative approach using GD.